# VS2013 Net 4_5_2 IIS7 signinManager.PasswordSignIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, security, iis

I am on hols for a week. Wont be able to answer during this time.

Expected Result
When using IIS with website user accounts then a user should be able to login with no issues.

Actual Result
After publishing to local IIS, DefaultConnection security string to MSSQLMS shows 'DOMAIN/USER$' as sql user not found when in fact  var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(); from Login.aspx.cs shows the user and password hash for all website users.

Recreating this bug:
I created a VS2013 aspx project (with MVC and webservices) and Individual Security Accounts, build and run project in debug. Add a user to create the localDB database and connection string. Change connection string to use local MSSQL server. Build and run project no probs. Create a user (localhost). Publish to IIS. Data is returned fine from the same MSSQL server (ApplicationData database). When logging in then receive error:
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\workstation$'.
MSSQLMS logs show the sql user not found. MSSQL profiler does not show the transaction.
The strange thing is that in Login.aspx.cs 'var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager();' shows all the users' details. The fail is on execution of 'var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);'.
I have added the user to MSSQL server Security, database and at the Table level.

Answer (score 0):

IIS uses the AppPool identity to communicate with other (network) resources. I'm not completly sure what you're trying to accomplish here but if you just want to host your identity db in SQL Server instead of using LocalDb, just give the AppPool identity of your IIS website the correct security clearances on the SQL server.

If you would like to do some kind of impersonation of the logged in user, you at first should not use 'Invidual Accounts' and secondly you have to setup impersonation in IIS. This can be done in the properties of the AppPool.